# The Comment&Like design with Redis

Tags: mysql, redis, facebook-like

I am drunk in the design of 'Comment & Like'!
I've finished the mysql works with the help in the stackoverflow,But when I am try to design the redis for it,I feel bad again -_-|||

**The situation is:**
When the client request the comment data from my service with the user info,service should tell client if the user had already liked the comment,Okay,I have 3 tables:User,Comment,Like(include user_id,and comment_id)
I'd like to select comments from table 'Comment' and use 'left join' to query out the like info from table 'Like'(with user_id and comment_id).It's the way solution for mysql.
I found that the query will be very slow if there have lots of Comments and Likes in the mysql DB,so,I have to use Redis to optimise it.But I am very confused when trying to work:
**1.**It's easy to cache data if the data have no relation with the user,I mean every user will get the same data,like the articles,post.
**2.**It's hard to cache data if the data have relation with the user,I mean every user will get the different data,like the 'like or not for a comment'

I am thinking about cache every Like info to redis,and query it out after the comment be queried,and set it into the comment.like.But the issue is that if I can not query the like info in redis, it could be caused by the crashing of redis,should I try to load from mysql again?If so,the redis make no means,mysql will be in heavy queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like/no like is just the same as yes/no, true/false, they are only binary information. Binary information can be easily recorded as 1/0. Therefore you should consider using bitmap to record this type of information.

This is a typical Redis bitmap usage, so instead of me copying and pasting these information from a blog, I shall introduce you to one that's been mentioned in the Redis official documentation: http://blog.getspool.com/2011/11/29/fast-easy-realtime-metrics-using-redis-bitmaps/

It is a quite detailed technical blog and come with code examples. I am sure you will find it useful.

Comment: I had tried to use bitmap,but I find that the bitmap will cost a lot memory.For example,if there are 1000000 user in my application, and only one user(the user_id=1000000) likes the comment,it will cost 1000000/8 KB memory to save 1 bit data,I think it's a bad way

Comment: I think the calculation is 1000000/8/1024 KB which is ~120K per comment. I would consider it is a benefit rather than a problem: 1) ~120K is maximum it needs to record up to 1M user's likes; 2) It will only reach that size when the last (1millionth) user liked it; 3) You can always offload the "old" like counts to your mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for you kindly suggestion~